# Does postgres hash string based primary keys under the hood?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm wondering about whether I could theoretically run into trouble if the IDs of rows are generated in a non-uniform way. Could I run into an issue where it's hard to shard the database table based on the primary key down the line?

I don't have direct control over these IDs as our customers use our API with an SDK and they dictate the IDs. They will probably use UUID v4 or some other similar UUID generator but I can't easily enforce this and I also don't want to.

I would have thought maybe postgres would be smart enough to automatically hash primary keys, non-cryptographically eg using xxHash, to avoid a sharding issue where sharding based on primary key could lead to unbalanced shards. Is that standard practice with database's or do databases generally assume the user will generate well distributed primary keys?

Comment: Advice: Use a UUID, that's almost guaranteed to be unique. Numbers will not be unique and will give you a headache. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens I've added context, I can't easily control the IDs directly

Comment: What kind of id do you use? An integer or something else? And integer will never be unique, not even when you hash is: 1 = 1 and 27364 will be 27364. And a database doesn't make any assumptions about your data, if you want an integer, you get an integer. If you want a UUID, you get one. It's up to you.

Comment: Right but it builds indexes on primary keys and for those B-trees to be well balanced it's probably going to re-hash things so that they index well?

Comment: You can find all details about the B-tree indexes over here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree.html

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you worried that the externally generated identifiers will cause conflicts?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm worried that externally generated identifiers will make it hard to shard the table

Comment: Conflicts are not an issue here @LaurenzAlbe it's up to the user to generate conflict free IDs

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question and describe how you are planning t shard the database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've updated the question, does that help clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few considerations about sharding, because that seems to be the reason for your question:

I'd say that sharding a tables based on the artificially generated primary key column is something rather unusual, and it is hard to conceive how that can be useful unless

- you always search that table with `WHERE id = ...`

and

- that table is never joined with any other table, or all other tables are small and replicated across all shards

Sharding is usually useful if you can split your database into shards that have little interconnection, for example, store each customer's data in a different database.

So I think that you should think harder about how and why you want to shard the database, before you start wondering about how PostgreSQL stores primary keys that are a string.

---

But to your original questions: PostgreSQL stores strings just as they are (unless they are very long, in which case they are compressed and stored out of line, but such values cannot be used as your primary key).  So no, there is no hashing under the hood.

That also applies to the standard B-tree indexes: strings are stored just as they are (which is important, since they must be ordered alphabetically). There are hash indexes in PostgreSQL, which wouldn't store the string, but its hashed value, but such indexes cannot be unique, so they cannot be used as primary key indexes.

Any hashing you want done, you have to do yourself, for example with `hashtext(id)`.

If you know that the values will be UUIDs, don't use a string data type, but use `uuid` by all means.